# Bring out variable from function on javascript

Tags: javascript

i have function like below

```
function showPosition(position) {
latOn = position.coords.latitude;
longOn = position.coords.longitude;
document.getElementById('lat').value=latOn;
document.getElementById('long').value=longOn;}

var locationx = new google.maps.LatLng(latO,longO);
latlng = locationx;
```

i want bring out "latOn and longOn" to

```
var locationx = new google.maps.LatLng('here');
```

help me please,...
thnks before

Comment: return `{latO:latO, longO:longO};`

Comment: what is the nature of your problem?

Comment: @Saar, where I can put the "return {latO, longO};"...?

Comment: Please post the complete code for your showPosition function (or at least where the "}" appears) and where var locationx = new google.maps.LatLng('here'); is used. Chances are you just need latOn, and longOn to be outside the scope of the function.

Comment: @feris, now I understand what is your problem. you receive the position from the geolocation right?

Comment: @Saar, yes,... can you help me

Comment: Where do you call `showPosition`?

Answer (score 0):

here you go: EDIT:

```
   var x = document.getElementById("demo");
var locationx = new google.maps.LatLng(-7.2574719, 112.7520883);
latlng = locationx;
var myLocation;
function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
      latOn = position.coords.latitude;
      longOn = position.coords.longitude;
      document.getElementById('lat').value = latOn;
      document.getElementById('long').value = longOn;
      myLocation = { latOn: latOn, longOn: longOn };
    }, showError);
  }
  else {
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}
```

Now every change of the location the variable `myLocation` will be the new location

If you want getLocation to return a value use:

```
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
var locationx = new google.maps.LatLng(-7.2574719, 112.7520883);
latlng = locationx;
var myLocation = getLocation();
function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    var location;
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
      latOn = position.coords.latitude;
      longOn = position.coords.longitude;
      document.getElementById('lat').value = latOn;
      document.getElementById('long').value = longOn;
      location = { latOn: latOn, longOn: longOn };
    }, showError);
  }
  else {
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
  if (location) {
    return location;
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry I am new.., how to post all the code here

Comment: create a fiddle, it will be easier http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: this my complete code, with php & mySQL https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzJbmNs8wPwGdEppNDZUUy1leUE/view